# Dynamic input fields and one javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have this js code:

```
function tickname(str,inpt) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById(inpt).value = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById(inpt).value = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "tck_name.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

According to sql query data php dynamically creates input fields

```
<input type="text" name="event_name_de" size="80" onkeyup="tickname(this.value,tick_de)" required><br>
<input type="text" id="tick_de" name="ticket_name_de" size="80" value="" readonly>

<input type="text" name="event_name_en" size="80" onkeyup="tickname(this.value,tick_en)" required><br>
<input type="text" id="tick_en" name="ticket_name_en" size="80" value="" readonly>

etc...
```

The problem is when i type some text in first field (name="event_name_de") and then another (name="event_name_en"), value changes only in input (name="ticket_name_de"). How to fix code, that input value will change according to current script logic?

P.s. sorry for my broken english :)

Comment: in your onkeyup functions, I think the 2nd param needs to be a string, tickname(this.value, 'tick_de')

Comment: yes it helped! :D thanks, silly error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle for the answer I gave in the comments

https://jsfiddle.net/ak00nta8/

```
 <input type="text" name="event_name_de" size="80" onkeyup="tickname(this.value,'tick_de')" required><br>
```